# Connect parallel lines to node

Tags: tikz-pgf

Sorry guys, I literally can't work out how to do this...

Consider the following figure:

[image]

This is drawn by:

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[rotate=+60]
      \foreach \x in {-0.3, -0.2, -0.1, 0.0, +0.1, +0.1, +0.2, +0.3}
        \draw[xshift=\x cm] (0, +2) -- (0, 0);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[rotate=-60]
      \foreach \x in {-0.3, -0.2, -0.1, 0.0, +0.1, +0.1, +0.2, +0.3}
        \draw[xshift=\x cm] (0, +2) -- (0, 0);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[rotate=180]
      \foreach \x in {-0.3, -0.2, -0.1, 0.0, +0.1, +0.1, +0.2, +0.3}
        \draw[xshift=\x cm] (0, +2) -- (0, 0);
    \end{scope}
    \fill[white]      (-1, -1) -- (+1, -1) -- (0, +1) -- cycle;
    \draw[very thick] (-1, -1) -- (+1, -1) -- (0, +1) -- cycle;
    \draw (0, -0.3) node {+};
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Now how do I add arrow heads to it? (I want each line to have an arrow head where it meets the triangle.)

As you can see, I already had to to some awful hack with drawing a white triangle over the top of those lines, since TikZ doesn't seem to allow arbitrary clipping. But clipping wouldn't be necessary if I could just make the lines stop at the edge of the triangle --- and that would also make adding arrow heads trivial.

After about an hour of trial and error, I *eventually* managed to make the syntax for connecting nodes actually work. But then all the lines converge to the center of the triangle, rather than remaining parallel like I want.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[name=add, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, draw, very thick] at (0, 0) {+};
  \begin{scope}[rotate=60]
      \foreach \x in {-0.3, -0.2, -0.1, 0.0, +0.1, +0.1, +0.2, +0.3}
        \draw[xshift=\x cm, ->] (0, +2) to (add);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Any hints?

Comment: Please try with `\draw[<-] (add.60)--+(60:2cm);`. Writting tikz code from an ipad is not so easy.

Comment: @Ignasi Very true. And in the past it was [even worse](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2649/12571)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the anchors to position your arrows, and, as @Ignasi suggests, specify coordinates in terms angles.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node(add)[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,draw,very thick,minimum size=2cm]{+};
  \foreach\ang[count=\i] in {60,180,300}{
  \begin{scope}[rotate=\ang]
  \foreach \x in {0,.1,.2,.3}{
    \draw[<-]([xshift=\x cm]add.side \i)--+(90:2cm);
    \draw[<-]([xshift=-\x cm]add.side \i)--+(90:2cm);
  }
  \end{scope}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Well... I pasted it in, and it works. I still haven't the vaguest idea _why_ it works, but hey...